# Label taskeng.exe console windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

At my job, we use a lot of console applications to run various processes.  We kick them off from the Task Scheduler on a regular and overlapping basis - at any time there could be anywhere from 3 to 20 `taskeng.exe` windows open, some with output from the task, some blank.

Is there any way we can relabel each window to indicate which console app it's associated with, or the name of the task that launched it?

Comment: I am not fully sure of how the structure of the Task Scheduler works (hence the comment, not answer): I know you can launch CMD windows/console programs with `start "Window Name" Program.exe` and the console window is titled "Window Name".  That may, however, require making custom launchers for them if the task scheduler doesn't work with that call.

Comment: @nerdwaller - Not a bad idea - it might be worth a try.  We had discussed having a custom launcher anyway, to handle auto-updating and such.  If there's no easy way to do it directly, I'll just add this to the goals for that project.

Comment: Hopefully someone else may have a simpler solution to save a bit of time.